# CoreControls is not defined error in PDFTron

Tags: typescript, pdftron

I'm continuously getting this error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: CoreControls is not defined`

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import DocumnetViewer = CoreControls.DocumentViewer;
declare const WebViewer: any;

@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('viewer') viewer: ElementRef;
wvInstance: any;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      /* some code */
      const documentViewer = new DocumnetViewer();
      documentViewer.displayPageLocation(3, 1, 3, true);
     /* some code */
}
}
```

Getting error on line no 2 .Please help me out of this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import DocumnetViewer = CoreControls.DocumentViewer;
```

It, not valid import syntax. Where you got this code?. Here is an example how to add pdftron to angular https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/angular/exist-project/

Comment: Ravin is correct. I will also leave the sample link for reference: https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-angularjs-sample. I also want to note that you can also access `CoreControls` through the `instance` in the recent versions.